# Grails joinTable query issue

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm, ggts

I have a User domain and a Role domain and a working joinTable coded on the User side as

```
static hasMany = [ roles: Role ]
...
static mapping = {
    table 'user_data'
    id column: 'employee_number', name: 'employeeNumber', generator: 'assigned', type: 'int'
    version false
    sort 'lastName'

    roles joinTable: [ name: 'user_role' ]

}
```

I am trying to query the database to pull all users with a security officer role with

```
def roleInstance = Role.find { name == 'security_officer' }
def secList = User.findAll("from User as u where u.roles = :roleInstance", [roleInstance:roleInstance])
```

But I am getting the error

```
Class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
Message: The value is not set for the parameter number 1.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with a bunch of guess and checking.

```
 def roleInstance = Role.findByName("security_officer")
 def query = User.where { 
     roles { 
         id == roleInstance.id 
     } 
 }
 def securityOfficerList = query.list()
```

Comment: accept your answer as the correct answer to remove this question as unanswered :-)

Comment: Had the same problem here.  Your solution worked.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Roles is a hasMany relationship so I think following should work.

```
def secList = User.findAll("from User as u where u.roles in (:roleInstance)", [roleInstance:[roleInstance]])
```

Answer (score 0):

User has many roles, so in query you can't  use u.roles = roleInstance.Try to use in [list of roles] or you can try the following query:
def secList = User.findAll("from User as u where u.roles in (from Role r where r.name=:roleInstance)", [roleInstance:roleInstance])

Comment: I am getting a new error Class: java.lang.ClassCastException // Message: Role cannot be cast to java.lang.String any ideas?

Comment: Replace [roleInstance:roleInstance] with [roleInstance:"security_officer"]